# Many-one degrees of some particular sets

Tags: computability

Let $W_0, W_1, W_2,\dotsc$ be an effective numbering of r.e. sets.

Consider sets $\text{Emp}=\{x\mid W_x=\emptyset\}$, $\text{Tot}=\{x\mid W_x=\mathbb{N}\}$ and $S_n=\{x\mid W_x=W_n\}$ (for some fixed $n$).

It is easy to show that $\text{Emp}$ is many-one reducible to $\text{Tot}$, but  $\text{Tot}$ is not many-one reducible to $\text{Emp}$. Moreover, for all $n$, $S_n$ is many-one reducible to $\text{Tot}$.

I was able to show that if $W_n$ is infinite, then $S_n$ and $\text{Tot}$ are many-one equivalent, i.e. have the same m-degree.

But what if $W_n$ is nonempty but finite? I have shown that the m-degree of $S_n$ is in such a case strictly greater than the m-degree of $\text{Emp}$. But is it strictly smaller then the m-degree of $\text{Tot}$, or maybe they are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact if $W_n$ is finite then $S_n$ is weaker than $\mathsf{Tot}$. This is because, in this case, $S_n$ is $\Sigma^0_1\wedge\Pi^0_1$-definable (or equivalently, is the intersection of a c.e. set and a co-c.e. set), while $\mathsf{Tot}$ is $\Pi^0_2$-complete.

Specifically, fix $n$ such that $W_n$ is finite, let $A=\{m: W_m\supseteq W_n\}$ and let $B=\{m: W_m\subseteq W_n\}$. Since $W_n$ is finite we have that $A$ is c.e. (if $W_n$ were infinite then $A$ would be merely $\Pi^0_2$) and $B$ is co-c.e. (Note that without an assumption on $W_n$, the most we could say is that $A$ and $B$ are each $\Pi^0_2$.) We clearly have $S_n=A\cap B$.

With this question we've stepped into the **difference (Ershov) hierarchy**; see the first section of [Stephan/Yang/Yu](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/%7Eyuliang/ssyy.pdf) for a good survey of its basic properties. Note that every set in the difference hierarchy is Turing-reducible to the Halting Problem, while $\mathsf{Tot}$ is strictly above the Halting Problem even with respect to Turing reducibility.

Comment: Dear Noah, thank you for your answer and the reference! Now I understand why my efforts (using only the machinery of Rogers classical book up to chapter 7) were unfruitful (but still I learned a lot).